# @Value is always null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-properties

I have a situation where my attempt to use a @Value annotation results in the value being a null.

This is part of a large project and I'm not sure which parts of it are needed.  I am using Java anotations (no xml file) and Spring boot.

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
public class RESTApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RESTApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

application.properties contains:

```
maxuploadfilesize=925000000
```

I did try to create a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer as some websites mentioned to do so.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Here is the class attempting to use it:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Value("${maxuploadfilesize}")
    String maxFileUploadSize;

    public String getMaxFileUploadSize() {
        return maxFileUploadSize;
    }

    public void setMaxFileUploadSize(String maxFileUploadSize) {
        this.maxFileUploadSize = maxFileUploadSize;
    }
}
```

However at runtime, maxFileUploadSize is always null.  Note the below debug comment where PropertySourcesPropertyResolver seemed to find its correct value within the application.properties file.

```
2015-06-10 13:50:20.906 DEBUG 21108 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'maxuploadfilesize' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]]
2015-06-10 13:50:20.906 DEBUG 21108 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'maxuploadfilesize' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]] with type [String] and value '925000000'
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are checking maxFileUploadSize? Also don't think you should need the AppConfig.

Comment: It is null in debugger but I am using it within a StringBuilder to generate a  policy String.

   StringBuffer policyStr = new StringBuffer();
   policyStr.append(maxFileUploadSize);

Comment: I mean the code that makes use of the MyClass bean. Where is that bean getting injected?

Comment: I removed AppConfig and get the same results.  Updating the application.properties file causes maxFileUploadSize to be found with the right value by PropertySourcesPropertyResolver in the DEBUG line of the logs but the @Value assignment doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like MyClass was not processed as SpringBean, which would mean, that the @Value-annotation was not processed.
You could check that with providing a default value, like  `@Value("${maxuploadfilesize:'100'}")`. If the value is still null, then you know, that MyClass is not instantiated as a SpringBean.

Since it is annotated with @Component, you should be able to simply inject it with
`@Autowired private MyClass myclass;`